# OrdinalIgnoreCase helper

Tags: c#

Could be useful?

```
OrdinalIgnoreCase s1 = "a";
OrdinalIgnoreCase s2 = "A";
Assert.AreEqual(s1, s2);
```

Where:

```
public class OrdinalIgnoreCase : IEquatable<OrdinalIgnoreCase>
{
    public static StringComparer Comparer { get; } = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

    public static implicit operator OrdinalIgnoreCase(string s) => new OrdinalIgnoreCase(s);
    public static implicit operator string(OrdinalIgnoreCase s) => s.Text;

    public OrdinalIgnoreCase(string text) => Text = text;
    public string Text { get; }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Comparer.GetHashCode(Text);
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    public virtual bool Equals(OrdinalIgnoreCase other) => Comparer.Equals(Text, other.Text);

    public static bool operator ==(OrdinalIgnoreCase left, OrdinalIgnoreCase right) =>
        Equals(left, right);

    public static bool operator !=(OrdinalIgnoreCase left, OrdinalIgnoreCase right) =>
        !Equals(left, right);

    public override string ToString() => Text;
}
```

Comment: It's super useful. I call it a [`SoftString`](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/blob/dev/Reusable.Core/src/SoftString.cs) and also trim the input. I hate bugs caused by case sensitivity and leading/trailing whitespace. This prevents a lot of trouble.

Comment: I wish to have String<TComparer> but there is no dedicated StringComparer specialization types in .NET for things like OrdinalIgnoreCase and C# support for static class API in templates is really bad.

Comment: My only comment would be that the implicit cast to `string` means it may be possible to use it in a situation where it isn't ordinal and ignoring case by accident, so I'd be tempted to remove it (but then I'd probably complain about how much effort it is to call `ToString()`).

Comment: @VisualMelon that's exactly the reason why I removed it from my implementation. It would be too easy to _downgrade_ this class into a normal string and transparently loose all the benfits. It'd be also unconventional to do so because implicitly casting to string would mean to _loose precision_. It's the same with `double --> int`, there is also no implicit conversion. You have to actively cast it. Using `ToString` is indeed not pretty but better less pretty then full of weird bugs ;-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Review

- I see no reason not to seal this class. No need for virtual methods.
- You prefer readability over argument checks: `Comparer.Equals(Text, other.Text)`
- I would make `!=` the opposite of `==` as blackbox:  `!(left == right);`
- If you want to be a bit more resilient to unicode shenanigans, you should do `text.Normalize();` (`á` is not always `á`, unless you normalize)

Comment: @t3chb0t this last step might be something for your SoftString. Don't know if you work with unicode..

Comment: I always hope I can get away with _not exactly knowing how encodigs work_ - I'll keep the normalization in mind in case it should bite me one day ;-]